# Mono for Android 4.0 Error compilation

Tags: c#, mono, xamarin.android

I have updated the lates version of mono for android 4.0, and in the runtime itg gets me an **Internal Error. Argument cannot be null. Parameter name: source.**
How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you provide more details about the problem? Look in the log for a stacktrace from the crash: http://docs.xamarin.com/android/advanced_topics/android_debug_log

Comment: Theres no more details, im using monodevelop on mac, and my project always orked fine but since i updated up to monodroid 4, when im trying to run the app into the emulator after trying to intall package and installing asenblies, it gets me that error that i mentioned it.

Comment: I create everything again, and throws me the same error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of MonoDevelop are you running? Mono for Android 4.0 requires v2.8.4.1

http://android.xamarin.com/Releases/Mono_for_Android_4/Release_4.0.0

**Edit**: This was [brought up on the mailing list](http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/monodroid/2011-December/007521.html) today and is a bug:

> This is a bug that's been identified today, and it's due to the project having external assembly references. While this is being fixed, disable "Fast Deployment" on the Project Options / Mono for Android Build panel.

Comment: I have MonoDevelop v2.8.4.1 and I am experiencing the same error.

Comment: its throws me the same error, i will continuing checking about this  problem...but if anybody can help me, would be helpful.

Comment: I have the Error, after Installing assemblies

Answer (score 0):

This was just fixed in MonoDevelop 2.8.4.2.

Download from: http://monodevelop.com/Download